# App Engine Flex executing servlet multiple times on 499 status code

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have created App engine flex project and have deployed it on google cloud with cron services pointing to one of the servlet. I have used request dispatcher for sequential execution of other servlets.My intial servlet is however getting executed multiple times.I can see status code 499 for get request.

[image]

Comment: This error could mean that your software closed the connection while the load balancer was processing the request. Most likely your program crashed. Time to debug.

Answer (score 0):

[499 error](https://httpstatuses.com/499) means that the connection has been closed on client-side, therefore nginx
returns this error if the connection closes while it is processing the request.

So the issue is on your side, providing some code will help to investigate where the error lies.